# How to convert xml to json in json value PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the result object encode with 'json_encode' PHP like this :

```
{ 
  output : { 
           name : 'john', 
           address : '<city>New York</city><country>United States</country>' 
         } 
 }
```

My expectation is :

```
{ 
   output : { 
           name : 'john', 
           address : {
                       'city' : 'New York',
                       'country' : 'United States'
                     }
         } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

consider $result as response. Below code will give json object

```
$string = "<?xml version='1.0'?> 
    <document>".
     $result.output.address
    ."</document>
    ";

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

    $json = json_encode($xml);
```